# Большое видео размером более 50 МБ в aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, aiogram

Как отправить большое видео размером более 50 МБ по URL-адресу в aiogram, используя `answer_video(url)`
Я получаю сообщение об ошибке, если размер видео превышает 50 МБ.
`aiogram.utils.exceptions.InvalidHTTPUrlContent: Failed to get http url content`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tdlib/telegram-bot-api
Hi, This link for telegram bot local server